# Scan QRcode using webcam in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, webcam

I am trying to create QR code. i've successfully created it using javascript qrcode. However, I don't know how to scan the QR code using a webcam in Javascript.

I've searched for it on Google and found https://qrcodescan.in/, but when I run the code in a local path I get the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker':
Script at 'https://qrcodescan.in/decoder.min.js' cannot be accessed
from origin 'null'.
```

I don't know how to rectify this error. Can you suggest how I could fix it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Download this js file on your localhost, and change the paths that link to it so that they point to your local version.

Comment: Thanks, I run to localhost, previous error is solved, I have received new error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined - decoder.min.js:1' Kindly suggest. what we do

Comment: Thanks, Now it is working fine, I didn't call path in correct way.